# Overloading = C++ more structures

Tags: c++

I'm doing program for people register and i have problem with overloading operator =.

I have class `CRegister`, struct `Person` and `Place`.

```
struct Places{
    char date[11];
    char * street;
    char * city;

Places & operator = (const Places & other){
        delete [] street;
        delete [] city;

        strncpy (date, other.date, 11);

        int len;
        len = strlen(other.street);
        this->street = new char[len];
        strncpy ( this->street, other.street, len );

        len = strlen(other.city);
        this->city = new char[len];
        strncpy ( this->city, other.city, len );

        return *this;
    }
}


struct Person{
    char id[12];
    char * name;
    char * surname;
    Places ** oldPlaces;

    int placesCount;
    int placesSize;
};

Person & Person::operator =(const Person& other){
    for (int i = 0; i < this->placesSize; i++){
         delete this->oldPlaces[i];
    }
    delete [] this->oldPlaces;
    delete [] name;
    delete [] surname;


    placesCount = other.placesCount;
    placesSize = other.placesSize;

    oldPlaces = new Places*[other.placesSize];

    strncpy (id, other.id, 11);

        int len;

        len = strlen(other.name);
        this->name = new char[len];
        strncpy ( this->name, other.name, len );

        len = strlen(other.surname);
        this->surname = new char[len];
        strncpy ( this->surname, other.surname, len );

    for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++){
        oldPlaces[i] = other.oldPlaces[i];
    }

    return *this;
}



class CRegister     
 {
   private:
    Person **persons;
    int personCount;
    int personSize;
 };

 CRegister& CRegister::operator =(const CRegister& other){
    for (int i = 0; i < this->personSize; i++){
        delete this->persons[i];
    }
    delete [] this->persons;

    personCount = other.personCount;
    personSize = other.personSize;

    persons = new Person*[other.personSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++){
        persons[i] = other.persons[i];
    }


    return *this; 
 }
```

However, the code has compiled but Netbeans shows me Run failed. Why?

Comment: not all operators can be overloaded. = it's one of these

Comment: @CapelliC Umm, what?!? Of course `operator=` **can** be overloaded.

Comment: 1. Use `std::string`. 2. Profit.

Comment: @CapelliC: of course you can overload op=, and in the rule-of-three case you even should.

Comment: @CapelliC: Yes it can. http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: Replace the arrays and pointer data members by standard library containers and/or strings, and you probably don't even have to implement your own assignment operators and copy constructors. You can then concentrate on more interesting problems.

Comment: I know i can, but for this case, when i have more structures i dont know why exactly :(

Comment: I think you'll *often* find that when you just **make up syntax**, your code won't work. What ever gave you the impression that the code you've posted was supposed to do anything at all? Refer to your lecture notes and your textbook for examples of how you're supposed to write your code.

Comment: This is homework for school and we cant use any stl library such as vector, string, etc...

Comment: @LukasHamrla You should have stated this in the question.

Comment: Never say just "is not working". Tell what you want it to do, and what happens instead!

Comment: From a comment below *"I have it there, sorry, i havent written it. It's compiled, but it has run failed"*  Please **edit your question** to include the real code and the real error you're trying to fix.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately, i had to reinstall my PC so i have only Windows and Netbeans show me only Run failed...

Comment: Sorry for bad question. Ive edit it.

Comment: @LukasHamrla Your new code doesn't compile either.  Please copy and paste the **actual code** so we're not simply fixing your typos.

Answer (score 2):

```
    len = strlen(other.city);
    this->city = new char[len];
    strncpy ( this->city, other.city, len );
```

This does not preserve the length of the string. How will later code know how long `this->city` is?

Comment: So i have to write len+1, the last position for '\0'?

Comment: That would be one way. Using `std::string` would make more sense though.

Comment: It is homework and we cant use string unfortunately...

Comment: Can you make your own string class? (I hope so, because forcing people to do things in very bad ways teaches them bad habits.)

Comment: This suffers from the same problem his original code does.  `strlen` doesn't count the final `'\0'`, but you _must_ copy it to the destination string.

Comment: @JamesKanze: What is the "this" you are referring to?

Comment: The code you show.  You need to allocate `strlen( source ) + ` bytes, in order to have space for the trailing `'\0'`.  (Also, you generally _don't_ want to use `strncpy`, because it doesn't guarantee a trailing `'\0'`.  And in this case, won't put one in the target string.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The code I show is his original code. As I pointed out, it doesn't preserve the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**. It could possibly be one reason if not the only reason.

On another note,

- Why not simply use `std::string`?
- Why not use **[copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)** ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're basically using C (wrapped in a class): you've made
what is probably the most frequent error in C code.  `strlen`
returns the number of characters in the string, *not* counting
the final `'\0'`.  `strcpy` copies the final `'\0'`, so one more
character,  If you use `strncpy` (as you do, which you
shouldn't), then you will end up with a string which is not
`'\0'` terminated.  So with `strcpy`, you overrun the end of
the buffer, and with `strncpy`, anyone trying to read the string
will overrun the end of the buffer (since they will continue
until a `'\0'`).

The rule is to allocate one more character than `strlen`
returns:

```
size_t len = strlen( other.name ) + 1;
name = new char[ len ];
strcpy( name, other.name );
```

(Although not standard C, many systems have a `strdup` function
which does this.  Using `malloc`, of course, so you would have
to free with `free`, and not `delete`.)

Beyond that, I will repeat what I said before: your code will
leave the object in an inconsistent state if any of the
allocations failed.  *Always* do everything which can fail
before modifying anything in your class.  The swap idiom is
classical for `operator=`, but otherwise, you can use local
pointers:

```
char* newName = NULL;
char* newSurname = NULL;
Places* newPlaces = NULL;

try {
    newName = strdup( other.name);
    newSurname = strdup( other.surname );
    newPlaces = deapCopyPlaces( other.places );
} catch ( ... ) {
    deepDelete( newPlaces );
    delete [] newName;
    delete [] newSurname;
}
//  And only now...
deepDelete( places );
delete [] name;
delete [] surname;
name = newName;
surname = newSurname;
places = newPlaces;
```

But the swap idiom is far preferrable, because it avoids having
to duplicate the all of the error handling code.